# Paste_Values in Google Scripts on a Google Sheet not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a very simple Google Script which I created to try and give my users the ability to add their name to a roster, without giving them the ability to edit the roster itself. I.e. Multiple people could sign up for a shift at 8:00am, but nobody can overwrite anyone else's name.

The user enters their name in a spreadsheet of times that looks as follows:
[image]

Once they've added their name and clicked the Submit button, it copies their name into a separate spreadsheet where I need to add the name into a cell of other names. It should look like this at the end:
[image]

To achieve this growing list, while not exposing the list to the editing user, I used the following code:

```
function Full() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Record'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Sale!C3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('E3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Everything works **Perfectly** except the final copy and paste. If I use the example of adding **George** as above, this is what I see after hitting submit:
[image]

What I don't understand is that if I run the final copy paste in it's own function, it works perfectly. It just doesn't work in this code block, and I don't understand why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As a bonus, my next step is to add functionality as well which checks if the name is already in the list, and if it is it doesn't get added twice. Any suggestions there would also be great, but are not needed.

Thanks

Comment: What calls Full?

Comment: The Submit button calls the Full function

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, could you please provide a copy or reproducible sample of both the Spreadsheet and related code?

Comment: I don't understand how that's possible. You can see all the raw data there and the code I ran against it?

Comment: That’s the value of [mcve] because it’s difficult to fix what we can’t reproduce.